# Enzyme Returns More Nodes Than Exist When Using Mount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

**component.tsx**

```js
import React, { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Form, FormControl, FormGroup, FormLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { StorageKeys } from "../ProtectedRoute";
import "./styles.scss";

const Login = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const handleSetEmail = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
        setEmail(event.target.value);

    const handleSetPassword = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
        setPassword(event.target.value);

    const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("email::", email);
        console.log("password::", password);
        localStorage.setItem(StorageKeys.TOKEN, "TODO: Auth");
        history.push("/");
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.removeItem(StorageKeys.TOKEN);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="login">

            <Card id="loginCard">
                <Card.Header>Login</Card.Header>
                <Card.Body>

                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <FormLabel>Email address</FormLabel>
                            <FormControl type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"
                                         value={email} onChange={handleSetEmail}
                                         required={true} />
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup>
                            <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                            <FormControl type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                                         value={password} onChange={handleSetPassword}
                                         required={true} />
                        </FormGroup>

                        <div className={"button-container"}>
                            <Button id="submit" variant="primary" type="submit">
                                Submit
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

This works when using `shallow` to render the component:

**login.test.tsx**

```js
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import Login from "./index";

describe("Login Component", () => {
    test("can properly submit form", () => {
        jest.spyOn(window.localStorage.__proto__, "removeItem");

        const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);

        // This works just find, finds only the one #email input.
        const emailInput = wrapper.find("#email");
        emailInput.simulate("change", { target: { value: testLoginData.email } });
    });
});
```

When using `mount` this throws the error:

```
Error: Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 2 found instead
```

```js
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import Login from "./index";

describe("Login Component", () => {
    test("can properly submit form", () => {
        jest.spyOn(window.localStorage.__proto__, "removeItem");

        const wrapper = mount(<Login />);
        const emailInput = wrapper.find("#email");

        // This will now complain about there being too many nodes.
        emailInput.simulate("change", { target: { value: testLoginData.email } });
    });
});
```

What gives? I need to use mount for the test that I'm working on, why is it finding multiple elements when there is for sure ONLY ONE.

I can patch it to work using the following, *but I shouldn't have to*... right?!

```js
emailInput.at(0).simulate("change", { target: { value: testLoginData.email } });
```

Answer (score 1):

So it's because your `<FormControl` is the first with this `id` and `<input` is second(or vice versa).

There are wide list of approaches:

1. `.at(0)` will work, but this way you will never know if you(because of error in the code) renders multiple elements. It might happen if conditions in conditional rendering `{someFlag && <....` that suppose to be mutually exclusive are not. So really, it's a bad way.
2. Mock `FormControl` to be final element  - so `<input` will not be returned anymore by `.find()`(honestly never used that, just assume it will work - but still looks messy and need additional boilerplate code for each test file, so not really handful way):

```
jest.mock('../FormControl.jsx', () => null);
```

3. use [`hostNodes()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/hostNodes.html) to filter only native elements(like `<span>` to be returned):

```
const emailInput = wrapper.find("#email").hostNodes();
```

I vote for 3rd option as most reliable and still safe for catching code logic's errors.